# React Native Expo - How to get Zebra Scanner pressed keyboard value without text input

Tags: react-native, expo, keyevent, zebra-scanners

I'm trying to develop React Native Expo app on Zebra Scanner OS android. I want to listen pressed F Keys or any physical keyboard events on main screen without text input. So far I tried couple of npm package but they didn't solve my problem.
And *keyboard* expo doc only works for 'keyboardDidShow' and 'keyboardDidHide'
Does anyone know how to handle *keyevents* on React Native Expo ?

https://github.com/chronsyn/react-native-keyevent-expo-config-plugin

This code didn't work.

```
import KeyEvent from 'react-native-keyevent';
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    KeyEvent.onKeyDownListener((keyEvent) => {
      console.log(`onKeyDown keyCode: ${keyEvent.keyCode}`);
      console.log(`Action: ${keyEvent.action}`);
      console.log(`Key: ${keyEvent.pressedKey}`);
    });

    KeyEvent.onKeyMultipleListener((keyEvent) => {
      console.log(`onKeyDown keyCode: ${keyEvent.keyCode}`);
      console.log(`Action: ${keyEvent.action}`);
      console.log(`Key: ${keyEvent.pressedKey}`);
    });
  });
```